# Running setup and teardown methods in python unittest once for multiple test modules

Tags: python, unit-testing, setuptools, python-unittest

I have a python package (setuptools) with many unittests in many test modules. I have defined the test folder in setup.py and currently run the tests using

```
python setup.py test
```

Inside each test module I define setUpModule and tearDownModule. These functions are identical across all test modules and are computationally costly. They create a large testing database and assign the location of this database to python variable inside each test module - so that the tests can find the database.

Is there anyway to run a setup method before the whole test suite starts (not just once for each module), pass a variable into the tests and and then run a tear down method after all of the tests in the test suite are finished?

In other words - there is setUp, setUpClass and setUpModule. Is there a way to do *setUpSuite*?

Comment: I had a similar case, where I just merged several testmodules into one single test module, this way I could save quite some setups and tear downs... (despite from the logic the modules should have stayed separated...)

Comment: Could you move the database provisioning outside of the test process and pass in the database config through the environment?